# Zig compiler complains of a nonexistent usize?

Tags: zig

The Zig compiler is giving me this error:
`src/gen.zig:27:11: error: expected type 'isize', found 'usize'`
    `for (0..config.maxRooms) |_| {`
         `~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
`src/gen.zig:27:11: note: signed 64-bit int cannot represent all possible unsigned 64-bit values`

The code it points to is

`for (0..config.maxRooms) |_| {`
    `var tries = config.roomDensity;`
    `while (tries > 0) {`
       `var w = rand.intRangeAtMost(u32,`
            `config.roomSize - config.roomSizeVarition,`
            `config.roomSize + config.roomSizeVarition`
        `);`
       `var h = rand.intRangeAtMost(u32,`
            `config.roomSize - config.roomSizeVarition,`
            `config.roomSize + config.roomSizeVarition`
        `);`
        `if (!tryAddRoom(&dungeon, w, h, &rand)) tries -= 1;`
    `}`
`}`

This doesn't seem to make any sense. `config.maxrooms` is a u32. Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: The problem was mixing up types 50 lines down, seems the compiler just gave the wrong line in the error